# Redirecting all files of a subfolder to the same files onto a new server

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have to redirect all static HTML files of a sub folder to a new location (a drupal version of the old site):

```
oldsite.net/topfolder/subx  =>  newsite.net/subx
```

but not all files exist anymore on the new site.
The missing files should be redirected to a main page in the new subfolder

With an example (please remark the target URLs have no “.html” extension):

```
oldsite.net/topfolder/subx/file1.html redirect to newsite.net/subx/file1 
oldsite.net/topfolder/subx/file2.html redirect to newsite.net/subx/file2
```

and

```
oldsite.net/topfolder/subx/missing1.html redirect to newsite.net/subx/mainpage
oldsite.net/topfolder/subx/missing2.html redirect to newsite.net/subx/mainpage
```

in the root .htaccess , I could write for each file something like that:

```
redirect 301 /topfolder/subx/file1.html  http://www.newsite.net/subx/file1
```

and for the missing files

```
redirect 301 /topfolder/subx/missing1.html http://www.newsite.net/subx/mainpage
```

But with more the 300 files it is a lot of work.

I am not quite expert with rewrite rules, I’m trying to write a rules, but it seems not to work.

This should work for the existing file (I did not jet tried it):

```
RewriteRule /topfolder/subx/^ (.*)\.html$  http://www.newsite.net/subx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But what for the missing files? And is the above rule right?

Any suggestion?
Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory **of oldsite**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^topfolder/(subx/[^.]+)\.html$ http://www.newsite.net/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Enable mod_rewrite and.htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory **of newsite**:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# not found then strip out query string and redirect to mainpage
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^new=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ subx/mainpage? [R=301,L]

# otherwise just strip out query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^new=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's sure a good idea, but on the new site I woulk like to have a its own 404 page. (mainpage for me is the mainpage of the "subx" subfolder ... I was not so clear in my post)

Comment: It did work on my local server, but not on the shared production server. I do not know why, simply the rule for oldsite is not applied (but any other rule works, i.e mod_rewrite is active). Anyway thank you (maybe I'll use the redirect 301 on each single file).

Comment: It it works on local computer it should (in theory) work on production server as well. It could be some local setup issues on that host.